# Has anyone designed a custom IoT wall switch?

Tags: raspberry-pi, zigbee

Are there any custom IoT wall switches designed using ZigBee, weave, Thread, etc. which have the ability to customize its use without forcefully imposing the use of a proprietary gateway or app?

I was thinking of using a RPI/Arduino solution to manage them instead. To turn them on and off yeah. Either via Google home/onhub or thru the custom RPI/Arduino.

Comment: Welcome to the IoT SE. Did you mean Z-Wave (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-Wave) where you wrote weave? Can you elaborate a bit what you want to do? Just on/off?

Comment: @Helmar the OP *probably* meant [Weave](https://developers.google.com/weave/), the Google platform for IoT.

Comment: To turn them on and off yeah. Either via Google home/onhub or thru the custom RPI/Arduino.

Comment: What I see in the market now it all connected to a Hub. Eg. Smart things or third party brands which has their own hub or RF remote which is not exactly "open".

Comment: Do you prefer wired switches or wireless switches? Is this a new house / apartment that's being built, a house / apartment that's being completely renovated, or do you just want to add a switch to an existing house / apartment and link it do whatever is already there?

Comment: I have existing switches(non smart). I'm thinking how do I get ZigBee or weave or thread onto the switches with compatibility on Google home, OnHub, raspberry pi and Arduino with ZigBee shield. Many wireless standards. Which ever works across the board. What I saw online is that thread seems to be the way to go now?

Answer (score 8):

The lightwaveRF lighting protocol is simple OOK at 433 Mhz, I think. It's documented, so you could use them. Maybe a little bit more  expensive than other options though.

Here is an Arduino/Raspberry Pi [library](https://github.com/roberttidey/LightwaveRF).

This is of course a solution with zero authentication or encryption, which ought to make it less attractive.

There also seem to be some WiFi switches coming out now, for example this [WeMo one](http://www.belkin.com/us/F7C030-Belkin/p/P-F7C030/)

Answer (score 6):

Z-Wave is a mesh networking technology commonly used for home automation that allows many different brands of products to interoperate with each other very easily.  However, it is a patented proprietary protocol that requires a licensed Z-Wave chip, which are not generally available to the hobbyist at affordable rates.

To communicate, Z-Wave devices must be joined to the same Z-Wave mesh network. That means you need to have a primary controller somewhere, at least for the purpose of pairing. The primary controller does not have to be present when the scene executes; and the primary controller does not necessarily have to be connected to the Internet (but that's not very IoT.)

Some commercial Z-Wave switches are "scene capable", meaning you can install and use them as a typical wall switch, and they can trigger behavior directly in other Z-wave devices without needing to send a message to the primary controller. Usually this is fairly primitive, meaning you can have one light switch turn on several other light switches, but nothing more sophisticated.

Comment: No one uses ZigBee or weave for home automation?

Comment: I wouldn't say "No one", but they're not as prevalent. Weave is a brand new higher level communication protocol that rides on top of TCP.  It doesn't specify a physical media that must be used; because it's TCP it works over Wi-Fi. I expect Google will push it hard. But most installed home automation networks today use custom protocols (Crestron, Z-Wave, X-10) that are purpose-built, older, simpler, and much smaller than TCP.  I expect a Z-Wave to Weave bridge will soon be forthcoming, if it doesn't already exist today.  And ZigBee's never really taken off in the commercial marketplace.